# How to allow CORS with MAMP

Tags: apache, mamp

I want to allow CORS with MAMP and understood that I need to add

```
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

in httpd.conf file but I don't know WHERE exactly.
I tried to add the line inside a `<Directry>`like

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Directory>
```

but nothing change...

Comment: After waiting 24h, now my MAMP allows CROS...